# Get / catch a button value before sending form, for form confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, confirmation

I just want to ask the user to confirm their choice before sending a form. So I need the text value (by that I mean the innerHTML, not the value="" attribute) they have just selected/clicked for them to confirm.
The form consists of many buttons with the same name but different values (dynamically generated), so I need to "catch" it once it has been selected.
The html looks like this:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="here.php">
<button class="bc" value="v1">foo</button>
<button class="bc" value="v2">bar</button>
</form>
```

I have this piece of code so far but I can't figure out how to get the value, to add it to the confirm box.

```
$('form#valueSelect').submit(function( event ) {
    var sel = this;
    var c = confirm("You have selected " + sel + " Click OK to continue?");
    return c;
});
```

I get [object HTMLFormElement] instead of the value. I tired `var sel = this.value;` and value() and val and val() but it doesn't work, I don't know why.

Comment: When you say "the value they have just selected", do you mean the button they clicked to submit the form?

Comment: Make sure you call a `event.preventDefault()` when the users answer `no` to the confirm, else the form will still be submitted.

Comment: Add your HTML code if you can.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how `sel = this.value` does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Try to have global variable and then update it when button click. You will have then recent button clicked value in it.

```
var btnText = '';
$(document).ready(function(){
$('form#valueSelect').submit(function( event ) {
    var c = confirm("You have selected " + btnText + " Click OK to continue?");
    return c;
});
$("input[name='YourBtnName']").on("click",function(){
btnText = $(this).val();
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my question wasn't quite clear.

I wanted the displayed value (innerHTML) of the button the user clicked (out of many other buttons), the html looks like this:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="here.php">
<button class="bc" value="v1">foo</button>
<button class="bc" value="v2">bar</button>
</form>
```

I found a workaround by using the click instead of the submit:

```
$('button.bc').click(function( event ) {
    var myForm = $('#myForm');
    event.preventDefault();
    var bval = this.value;
    var choice = this.innerHTML;
    var c = confirm("You have selected " + choice + "\nClick OK to continue?");
    if(c == true) {
        var input = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "token").val(bval);
        $('#myForm').append($(input));
        $('#myForm').submit();
    }
});
```

and adding `<input type="hidden" name="token"></input>` in my form, in order to "store" the value of the clicked button.